# How to use SearchView with AppCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat, searchview

I used `SherlockActionBar` for my `ActionBar`, but I want to use AppCompact for my search view. To change my code from sherlock to AppCompact, I wrote this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        //searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
       // return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

xml menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

but it crashed. How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
**change**    android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass

Comment: Can you paste the crash stack?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.p30droid.appvs, PID: 2202
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.p30droid.appvs.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:89)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)

Comment: > android:actionViewClass
should be app:actionViewClass

Comment: searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()